# Moq: Setup a property without setter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, properties, moq

I have following class:

```
public class PairOfDice
{
    private Dice d1,d2;
    public int Value 
    {
       get { return d1.Value + d2.Value; }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to use a `PairOfDice` in my test which returns the value 1, although I use random values in my real dice:

```
[Test]
public void DoOneStep ()
{
    var mock = new Mock<PairOfDice>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.Value).Return(2);
    PairOfDice d = mock.Object;
    Assert.AreEqual(1, d.Value);
}
```

Unfortunately I get a `Invalid setup on non-overridable member` error. What can I do in this situation?

Please note, that this is my first try to implement Unit-Tests.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use `.SetupGet` on your mock object.

eg.

```
[Test]
public void DoOneStep ()
{
    var mock = new Mock<PairOfDice>();
    mock.SetupGet(x => x.Value).Returns(1);
    PairOfDice d = mock.Object;
    Assert.AreEqual(1, d.Value);
}
```

See [here](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/Mock(T)/M/SetupGet(TProperty)) for further details.

Comment: Still has exactly the same problem, as mentioned above the problem is that it is not virtual.

Comment: SetupGet is the correct method, regardless and the correct answer. Creating a virtual of a field that will NEVER be overridden or has no need, is plain silly, and may violate what the developer wants to secure. This is a simple problem and making the field virtual probably has little affect, but in the real world, making something virtual just so you can test it is incorrect, which is why you CAN mock the value using SetupGet.

Comment: @Jim, your link now goes to a 404, is there any way you can update it? +1 for the same reason iGanja mentions above.

Comment: You could create an interface for the class, and both use and mock the interface instead- removing the requirement to make stuff unnecessarily virtual. Passing around interfaces instead of concrete classes is much nicer to write tests with.. + IoC if you need it...
Side Note: putting hyperlinked "here" 's is annoying for screen readers.

Answer (score 22):

Your problem is because it's not `virtual`. Not because you don't have a setter.

Moq cannot build up a Proxy because it cannot override your property. You either need to use an Interface, virtual method, or abstract method.

Comment: Is there a disadvantage setting this property to virtual?

Comment: Only if you consider sub-classes `override`-ing that function a risk. Basically nothing noteworthy unless it's a super secure function you can't trust other classes to get right, however those you shouldn't be mocking anyway as they wouldn't be public.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete as Moq is able to mock non-virtual properties.

Comment: @krillgar can you provide a link with further documentation?